# Web Scraping data from elements of a certain class?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am working on a personal project in which I am attempting to pull the Width, Height, and Depth information for various appliances from a Home Dpot Webpage such as this one:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/LG-Electronics-29-5-cu-ft-Smart-French-4-Door-Door-In-Door-Full-Convert-with-Craft-Ice-Refrigerator-in-PrintProof-Stainless-Steel-LRMDS3006S/312285857

The dimensions are about halfway down the page and look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4lMU.jpg

I am having trouble scraping those values out of the page. I tried using the Div classes that they were under but they seem to describe the table cell dimensions and not specifically those values. If this is the case I can put them into lists/dicts and search for the ones I want, but I can't seem to scrape them at all. My current code looks like:

```
specList = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "specifications__row col__12-12 col__12-12--xs col__12-12--sm col__6-12--md"})
        print(specList)
```

Any ideas folks? I'm coming up dry online searching.

Mark

Comment: That data is loaded in dynamically when the page is scrolled, you'll need to use selenium or similar to execute all the JS on the page and grab the content after simulating a scroll

Comment: Oh so I need to virtually scroll down to that section first and then use the request module at that point and the days will populate?